# Using a nosql database for very large dataset with small data size highly written and moderate read

Tags: java, mongodb, riak, nosql

what is a better nosql database for creating a system to record advertisement data for about 50 to 200 millions insert per day, the aggregation of the data will be used to show the pattern of how users engage with the ads. I really like MongoDB but it seems that  major industry players are picking Riak for the job. It seems that Mongo had to flush some caveats in last 2 releases and the current version seems to be pretty good for the job, any idea?

Comment: This question isn't a good fit for StackOverflow. It's too broad and will have too many opinions, especially given how little we know about your actual programming problem your facing. "Major industry players are picking Riak?" Really? What players?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems mongodb with hadoop (http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-hadoop/ ) fits your data requirements.  You can store data in mongodb and run aggregation jobs (map/reduce) on hadoop cluster.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Java Berkeley DB from Oracle.

Very powerful and easy to use Open source but not free.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a type of question that could be answered as `Product1` or `Product2`. It is just too small amount of information given. There is no info about the environment, where the system will run, what type of information will be inserted, how are you going to aggregate it.

The best way is to try:

1. write a test using `Product1`,
2. write a the same thing with a `Product2`
3. start inserting the data which looks as close as possible to the
   data you are assuming to get in real environment
4. make measurements of speed and whatever factors you need

and only based on that you will be able to determine what suits you